# SyntaxError: invalid syntax On VsCode Python

Tags: python, visual-studio, syntax-error

i Just cant use print(f'') in vscode [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6KYZ.png)

Comment: Please add your code in text in your question.

Comment: the problem is the VsCode i can run the same on the terminal:

Comment: nome = 'Fabio'
idade = 18
altura = 1.75
peso = 55
anoAtual = 2019
Nascimento = anoAtual-idade
imc = peso / altura**2
'''
'''
# {imc: .2f}')
print(f'{nome} tem {idade}, {altura} e pesa {peso}\n seu imc eh {imc: .2f}')

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, turns out my interpreter was not set.
In VSCode, go to `File>Preferences>Settings` and search for "`python.pythonPath`" and set it to your interpreter path.

If you are using a Virtual Environment, search for "`python.venvPath`" and add a global environment PATH.